# Tkinter GUI window stops working in the background

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a Python Data Analyzer using Tkinter as the GUI for it. The job of the program is to pull the data, perform some calculations on it then display the results on the Tkinter GUI. Using these displayed results, I am going to be performing other tasks on another app. My problem is that once I click on the other app (or any app that is not the Tkinter GUI window) the GUI stops displaying the information in real time as it was doing before.

I want the GUI to still display the data even though I am using the other application.

Here is sample code that gives an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set('hello')

l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()

for i in range(100):
    sleep(0.5)
    var.set('goodbye' if i%2 else 'hello')
    root.update_idletasks()
```

So if you run this program and click on something else, e.g. the desktop, the window will freeze at the last word it displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a loop with `time.sleep` which blocks tkinter's main thread, you should use `root.after` for this kind of operations:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set('hello')

l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()

def func(counter):
    var.set("goodbye" if counter % 2 else "hello")
    counter+=1
    if counter<100:
        root.after(500, func, counter)

root.after(500, func, 0)

root.mainloop()
```